# Find Condition by And doen't work + cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

This function is working on OR condition. I need this to work with AND condition.
Any help:

```
$ands = array();
foreach ($array_training_id as $id) {
        $ands[] = array('TrainingsUser.training_id' => $id);
}
$conditions = array('AND' => $ands);
$users = $this->TrainingsUser->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```

I'd like to write a query AND condition like this:

```
SELECT user_id FROM trainings_users WHERE training_id = 172 AND training_id = 174
```

This query is working when is getting the first id.
Table explanation:
I have 3 table Training - User - Training_users... **Training_users table have the traing_id and user_id** What I want I need is some thing like this :  `SELECT user_id FROM Training_users WHERE training_id = 172 AND training_id = 174`... which it doesn't work even in SqlMyadmin

[image]

what i need when I give training_id 172 AND training_id 174 it have to return user 150 only

Comment: Please post your model relations to clarify them.

Comment: I want to write a query like this. SELECT * FROM Training WHERE project_ids = 3 AND project_ids = 6 AND project_ids = 11

Comment: Again: please specify your relations (the ones you declared in your models)

Comment: Training ---->   var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
  'User' => array(
   'className' => 'User',
   'joinTable' => 'trainings_users',
   'foreignKey' => 'training_id',
   'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',

Comment: You can update your question with it. Thats better as putting it into a comment.

Comment: Mark Thank you for your response.I think we are near there. but still doesn't work. Ok... let's be more clear... I have 3 table Training - User - <b>Training_users... Training_users table I have the traing_id and user_id</b> What I want I need is some thing likethis : { SELECT user_id FROM Training_users WHERE training_id = 172 AND training_id = 174}... which it doesn't work even in SqlMyadmin

Comment: What you just posted still does NOT require any AND, but OR. You should really get your sql straight first :)

Comment: but this statement is incorrect isn't it? .... SELECT user_id FROM Training_users WHERE training_id = 172 AND training_id = 174 -- cause it gives me empty -- but when I try -> SELECT user_id FROM Training_users WHERE training_id = 172 -- It works

Comment: I added my table photo-> what i need when I give training_id 172 AND training_id 174 it have to return user 150 only

Comment: did you try OR? as I suggested the last 3 times?

Comment: If you mean this => SELECT user_id
FROM trim_trainings_users
WHERE training_id =172
OR training_id =174----yes I did. but it returns all the 172 and 174 fields. I mean it's the same

Comment: I answered the question down here you can find it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why is your $array_project_id a string in the first place (besides the naming conflict^^)?
It should be an array of ids and cake will automatically be able to work with it out of the box.

Well, anyway:

```
$ids = explode(',', $array_project_id);
// now its a clean array

$users = $this->Training->find('all', array('conditions' => 
    array('Training.Project_id' => $ids)
));
```

After your comments I still don't see the value in using AND here.
But what the heck, here you go:

```
$ands = array();
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $ands[] = array('Training.Project_id' => $id);
}
$conditions = array('AND' => $ands);
$users = $this->Training->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```

Voila. It will still never work, though.

It seems you are using some HABTM relation (you should have provided this vital piece of information in the beginning!). Then you need to query the intermediate model/relation in order to have two belongsTo-relations (= left joins) here.

What you REALLY need (again: why did you just post the relevant relation and the information about Training_users now?) is to query the intermediate table "Training_users" with one contain in the belongsTo direction (left joins to users).
And the most important fact: using OR instead of AND. This will get the results you want.

Comment: You want AND? for several ids? that makes no sense since it can always only belong to one. you would always get an empty result, would you not?

Comment: Well yes. What you suggest? Well there should be a way.  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html. I wrote an answer below I put the IDs in array which it return OR. I mean all the project_ids for these 3 items.

Comment: Mark Thank you for your response.I think we are near there. but still doesn't work. Ok... let's be more clear... I have 3 table Training - User - <b>Training_users... Training_users table I have the traing_id and user_id</b> What I want I need is some thing likethis : { SELECT user_id FROM Training_users WHERE project_ids = 172 AND project_ids = 174}... which it doesn't work even in SqlMyadmin

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be, to create a habtm-relation.

Then you can do:

```
$users = $this->User->Training->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.id =' => $ids)));
```

This finds all where User.id = $id

With your AND-condition, it would be:

```
 $users = $this->User->Training->find('all', array('conditions' => 
'AND' => array('User.id =' => $ids['n'], 'User.id =' => $ids['n'])
));
```

Comment: No...My friend I have to get the training_ids to have user_ids

Comment: Then just turn it around: $this->Training->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Trainig.id =' => $ids)));